# Define Brush as Resource getting its color from another resource

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to define a brush which gets its color from another resource. Just like that

```
 <Color x:Key="MyColor">#003C83</Color>
 <Brush x:Key="MyColor.Brush" Color="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `Brush` is an abstract class and as such cannot be instantiated. Visual Studio and the compiler tell you as much if you pay attention to the error messages they provide. Look at the documentation for `Brush` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brush?view=netframework-4.7.1) to see which concrete brush classes inherit from `Brush` and pick one that suits you.

Comment: @elgonzo Note however that `<Brush x:Key="MyColor.Brush">#003C83</Brush>` works, due to automatic type conversion. XAML is not C#.

Comment: @Clemens yes, but this is not equivalent to the XAML markup in the question. In the XAML example in your comment you have a string value that is being converted to a particular brush type by the type converter. Note that in the question, there is no string value for the brush, but it is attempted to assign an actual Color instance to the Color property of the Brush (`Brush` doesn't have a Color property). In this case, there is no type conversion involved with respect to the brush (there is type conversion involved to create the Color instance, though)

Comment: Sure, that's obvious. All I want to say is that writing `<Brush>` in XAML is not generally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a specific type of Brush as it is an abstract class as @elgonzo stated... Here is a simple example with `SolidColorBrush`:

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLTest.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XAMLTest"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="MyColor">#003C83</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor.Brush" Color="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource MyColor.Brush}" BorderThickness="5" Background="Yellow" Height="20" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

Do try to read the [WPF Brushes Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-brushes-overview) on MSDN...